# How to find out the cell is empty in datagridview in c#.net

Tags: datagridview, datagridviewcellstyle

In datagridview how to find out the cell is empty when iam leaving the cell,if it is empty i want to handle that cell,i.e ristrict the user  go forward.if data fill user can go forword normally,how can acheave this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the event of `DataGridView` [`CellValidating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) or [`RowValidating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidating.aspx)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter some text before you leave.");
            }
            else
            {
                //Some logic here
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: then you can mark my post +1 as a useful answer and welcome :)